# error message evaluation system with PHP eval()

Tags: php, eval

I'm trying out a error message evaluation system but I havn't been able to get it to work to acctually be able to evaluate the system.

Can you see what is wrong with it?

```
    $errors     = array();
    $name       = '9';
    $familyname = 'family';
    $user       = '9user`';
    $postdata   = array('name' => $name,'familyname' => $familyname,'user' => $user);

    foreach($postdata as $key => $value)
    {
        switch($key)
        {
            case 'name':
                $rules = array
                (
                    'strlen($value)>1;'               => 'Your name is too short.',
                    'is_numeric(substr($value,0,1));' => 'Your name has to begin with a character.',
                    'has_specchar($value);'           => 'Your name contains illegal characters.'
                );

                foreach($rules as $rule => $error)
                {
                    if(eval($rule)) $errors[] = $error;
                }
                break;

            case 'familyname':
                break;

            case 'user':
                $rules = array
                (
                    'strlen($value)<5;'               => 'The username is too short.',
                    'is_numeric(substr($value,0,1));' => 'The username has to begin with a character.',
                    'has_specchar($value);'           => 'The username contains illegal characters.'
                );

                foreach($rules as $rule => $error)
                {
                    if(eval($rule))
                    // if(eval($rule)==1)
                    // if(eval($rule)===1)
                    // if(eval($rule)==true)
                    // if(eval($rule)===true)
                    // None of these have had an effect??!
                    {
                        $errors[] = $error;
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
        }
    }
    print_r($errors);

    function has_specchar($x,$excludes=array())
    {

        if(is_array($excludes)&&!empty($excludes))
        {
            foreach($excludes as $exclude)
            {
                $x=str_replace($exclude,'',$x);        
            }    
        } 

        if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i',$x))
        {
            return true;        
        }

        return false;

    }
```

This error array is empty even though I've entered data I know *SHOULD* trigger it to become an error??!

Comment: That approach is a very exotic one, has been followed millions of times and always proven to be a bad idea. One does not store code inside strings. It is inefficient, insecure and there is no need to do so. Code and text are two separate things. Do not mix them.

Comment: arkascha, You see what I'm trying to accomplish. Do you have a suggestion to how to better approach the situation? Like I say. I'm glad for the feedback.

Comment: Don't try to somehow "abstract" those rule sets. Code them in conservative conditionals, that is much more robust. If you really insist on such fancy stuff, then use dynamic functions or lambdas, but do not use `eval()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP documentation:

> eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned. As of PHP 7, if there is a parse error in the evaluated code, eval() throws a ParseError exception. Before PHP 7, in this case eval() returned FALSE and execution of the following code continued normally. It is not possible to catch a parse error in eval() using set_error_handler().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Adding `return` to your rules keys seems to fix the problem.

```
    $rules = array
    (
        'return strlen($value)>1;'               => 'Your name is too short.',
        'return is_numeric(substr($value,0,1));' => 'Your name has to begin with a character.',
        'return has_specchar($value);'           => 'Your name contains illegal characters.'
    );
```

Comment: Solved by adding `return` in the rule key `'return strlen($value)<5;'`. I feel so dumb :(

Feel free to evaluate the approach instead if you like. I'm glad to get feedback.