# Validating POST data class

Tags: php, validation, class

This is an extension of a [question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42904474/error-message-evaluation-system-with-php-eval?noredirect=1#comment72943797_42904474) that was deemed to be unsafe practise, due to the use of `eval()`. So I went for another approach but I have run into a problem. I do not know how to convert it to a class. My attempt ends with an error when I try to use `call_user_func_array`. it can't find the function in the class. Can you give me some hint so I get going? Thanks!

The error message I get when I try to run my code is `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'testlength' not found or invalid function name` but on all validation methods. This is what I don't understand. This is what I want help to understand why it does not work.

```
class ruleValidator
{

    protected $postData = array();
    protected $ruleSet  = array();
    var $exceptions = 'Å,Ä,Þ,å,ä,þ,Ø,Ö,Ð,ø,ö,ð,Æ,Ü,æ,ü,á,é,í,ñ,ó,ú,ü,Á,É,Í,Ñ,Ó,Ê,Ú,Ü,ß';

    function __construct(){
        $this->exceptions = explode(',',$exceptions);
    }

    function testlength($string,$threshold)
    {
        return strlen($string)<$threshold?
            'Your %s is too short.': // TRUE
            '';                      // FALSE
    }

    function testnumeric($string,$offset,$length,$switch=true)
    {
        if(is_numeric(substr($string,$offset,$length))===$switch)
        {
            return $switch?
                'Your %s has to begin with a character.': // Truely TRUE
                'Your %s is containing non numeric characters. Please enter only digits.'; // Falsely TRUE
        }
    }

    function testemail($string)
    {
        return filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)?
            '':                                   // TRUE
            'Your email is not in a valid form.'; // FALSE
    }

    function testpattern($string,$pattern='/^[0-9]{8,10}$/')
    {
        return preg_match($pattern, $string)?
            '': // TRUE
            'Your %s is entered incorrect. Please use the correct format when entering data.'; // FALSE
    }

    function testequalto($string1,$string2)
    {
        return $string1==$string2?
            '':                                       // TRUE
            'Your %s fields do not match eachother.'; // FALSE
    }

    function testchecked($bool)
    {
        return $bool===true?
            '':                                               // TRUE
            'You are required to check this %s to continue.'; // FALSE
    }


    function testspecchar($string,$excludes=array())
    {
        if(is_array($excludes)&&!empty($excludes))
        {
            foreach($excludes as $exclude)
            {
                $string=str_replace($exclude,'',$string);        
            }    
        }

        if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i',$string))
        {
            return 'Your %s contains illegal characters.'; // TRUE
        }

        return;                                            // FALSE

    }

}
```

This is an array with how the POST data is recieved in the validator and the rules I use for the different fields in the form.

```
    $exceptions = explode(',','Å,Ä,Þ,å,ä,þ,Ø,Ö,Ð,ø,ö,ð,Æ,Ü,æ,ü,á,é,í,ñ,ó,ú,ü,Á,É,Í,Ñ,Ó,Ê,Ú,Ü,ß');
    $postData = array
    (
        'name'             => 'Mikael',
        'familyname'       => 'Eriksson`',
        'username'         => 'Mik',
        'password'         => 'testtest',
        'password-confirm' => 'testtesty',
        'email'            => 'try.to@guess.it,se',
        'phone'            => '0000000000a',
        'policy'           => 0
    );
    $ruleSet = array
    (
        'name'=>array
        (
            'testlength'=>2,
            'testnumeric'=>array(0,1),
            'testspecchar'=>array($exceptions)
        ),
        'familyname'=>array
        (
            'testlength'=>2,
            'testnumeric'=>array(0,1),
            'testspecchar'=>array($exceptions)
        ),
        'username'=>array
        (
            'testlength'=>4,
            'testnumeric'=>array(0,1),
            'testspecchar'=>array()
        ),
        'email'=>array
        (
            'testemail'=>array()
        ),
        'phone'=>array
        (
            'testnumeric'=>array(0,strlen($postData['phone']),false),
            'testpattern'=>'/^[0-9]{8,10}$/'
        ),
        'password'=>array
        (
            'testlength'=>8
        ),
        'password-confirm'=>array
        (
            'testequalto'=>$postData['password-confirm']
        ),
        'policy'=>array
        (
            'testchecked'=>array()
        )
    );
```

Here is how I validated the data up until now. It works, but I want to make this to a class to streamline the code in my project.

```
    foreach($postData as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($key,$ruleSet))
        {
            $errors[] = "The field `$key` is not part of the form. Only send actual form data.";
            break;
        }

        $slice = array($key=>$ruleSet[$key]);
        foreach($slice as $rules => $rule)
        {
            foreach($rule as $rls => $r)
            {
                $r = array_merge((array)$value,(array)$r);
                $errors[] = sprintf(call_user_func_array($rls,$r),$key);
            }
        }
    }
    if(count($errors)>0) return implode(';;',array_filter($errors,'strlen'));
```

Comment: You have no where a `new` statement to initialize the classes and you have not marked the methods  `static` to call them without constructing.

Comment: Thanks but that is not what I'm asking. I know I have no init. The problem is that I get `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'testlength' not found or invalid function name` but not just on `testlength` but all validation methods. This is what I want help to understand or to translate the code to work in a class.

Comment: dump all your `$rls` what is in them?

Comment: @Cirshiss yes it is the problem you are asking for a solution. You have no callable classe because you did not `new` them and they are not `static` either

Comment: `call_user_func_array("ruleValidator::$rls", $r)`

Comment: Updated the code to mirror the changes I've made.

Comment: @Deadooshka, your code worked. When I saw I hade named `$postdata` -> `$postData` I changed it and now the code work. Thanks dude. Don't know how to make your answer as Correct/Solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Deadooshka for providing me with the solution.

```
call_user_func_array("ruleValidator::$rls", $r)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call a method of a **class**, you have to make an instance (using `new`) or call them statically when the methods are declared `static`.

In both ways, you have to tell `call_user_func_array()` that you are not calling a function in the global scope, but from within a class.

```
call_user_func_array(array('ruleValidator', $rls), $r)
```

Then declare the functions static:

```
public static function testlength($string,$threshold) {

}
```

Or with `new`:

```
$slice = array($key=>$ruleSet[$key]);
$callbackClass = new ruleValidator();
foreach($slice as $rules => $rule)

/** ... */

call_user_func_array(array($callbackClass, $rls), $r)
```

Comment: I made the changes `public static` and added the line `$callbackClass = new ruleValidator();` and changed the callback `call_user_func_array(array($callbackClass, $rls), $r)` This results in: `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function ruleValidator::testequalto(), 1 passed on line 33 and exactly 2 expected Stack trace: #0 php_class_validator.php(33): ruleValidator->testequalto('testtesty') #1 php_class_validator.php(167): ruleValidator->validateData(Array, Array) #2 {main} thrown in php_class_validator.php on line 72`

Comment: @Cirshiss when you make a new instance with `new` the methods should not be `static`. When you call the class statically with `::` it should have `static` methods.